# Allowing bookings of o365 room for external users

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I have a O365 tenant with a bunch of resources (=rooms) in it, e.g. `room1@foo.com`, and a few users, e.g. `user1@foo.com`.

The rooms are possible to book for users within the tenant, i.e., `user1` may schedule a meeting in `room1`, but I now want to make them available also for some external users, let's call it `test@bar.com`.

I've read a ton of guides such as [this](https://resolve.co.uk/blog/article/allow-external-users-to-book-in-office-365-resource-calendar) and [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharing-meeting-rooms-between-2-office365/c5d6ba4e-678a-49c1-8780-ca39fdb2c0d0) and [this](https://dotsh.no/2020/02/14/enable-external-booking-of-meeting-rooms/) about this, and they all pretty much say the same thing; it's the `ProcessExternalMeetingMessages` property that allows this. If it's enabled, by default *anyone* should be able to send a scheduling request to the resource's mailbox.

So from PowerShell I've done

```
> Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity Room1 -ProcessExternalMeetingMessages $true
```

I've verified that the change is in effect:

```
> Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity Room1 | fl ProcessExternalMeetingMessages

ProcessExternalMeetingMessages : True
```

I've also published the calendar:

```
> Set-MailboxCalendarFolder Room1:\Calendar -PublishEnabled $true
```

This gives me a public URL in which the calendar is viewable with free/busy information.

Furthermore, I've added my user as a delegate to the resource so that I can view its mailbox, verified that "Everyone" is allowed to book the resource, verified that there are no custom transport rules preventing e-mail delivery to the resource, and even explicitly shared the calendar with my external user `test@bar.com`.

Still, when trying to book a meeting with the resource as the location, there's never any response. The event is not added to the room calendar, there is no accept/decline answer sent back to the booking user, and there is no invitation e-mail in the resource's mailbox. It's clear that external meeting requests are *not* processed.

If I book the room from `user1@foo.com`, it instantly responds with an accept, and in the resource's mailbox the received invitation and the sent response is visible.

I feel like I've turned every stone now, trying to understand why this room cannot be scheduled. Every guide says that if `ProcessExternalMeetingMessages` is `true`, by default *anyone* may schedule that resource, but I cannot even do it after explicitly publishing and sharing the calendar with my particular user.

How could I debug this further? Is there any global setting that could override the `ProcessExternalMeetingMessages` settings, such as a policy that blocks or restricts external messages on a higher level?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little something, if you come across mail boxes calendar folders in another language.

## This gets the calendar folder regardless of language.

```
$calendar_folder = get-mailboxfolderstatistics $RoomID -folderscope calendar | where {($_.foldertype -eq "Calendar")} | select name 
$calendar_folder_name = $RoomID+":\"+$cal.name
```

Also what do you want to share, the meeting title, or just the organiser or both?
# Meeting details in calendar to be shown.

```
set-calendarprocessing -Identity $RoomID -DeleteSubject $false -AddOrganizerToSubject $true
```

Get permmissions of calendar_folder

```
$calendar_folder_permissions = Get-MailboxFolderPermission 
$calendar_folder_name | where {$_.User -notmatch "^(Default|Anonymous)$"}
```

Get and remove permissions

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission $calendar_folder_name | where {$_.User -notmatch "^(Default|Anonymous)$"} | % { Remove-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $_.Identity -User $_.User.DisplayName -Confirm:$false
```

Add-MailboxFolderPermission (adds) / Set-MailboxFolderPermission (overwrites), You can use groups or people

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission $calendar_folder_name -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails
Set-MailboxFolderPermission $calendar_folder_name -User Default -AccessRights AvailabilityOnly
Add-MailboxFolderPermission $calendar_folder_name -User $GroupName -AccessRights LimitedDetails
```